# Using PyInstaller to create single exe when there are non python files that need to be included?

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, pyinstaller

Is there a way to use PyInstaller to create a single executable that also includes things such as text files and .ui files? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you are talking about QT .ui files, PyInstaller is aware of QT and will just work. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add items to a pyinstaller built exe using the [spec file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files):

> For example, to add a single README file to the top level of a one-folder app, you could modify the spec file as follows:

```
a = Analysis(...
     datas=[ ('src/README.txt', '.') ],
     ...
     )
```

> You have made the datas= argument a one-item list. The item is a tuple in which the first string says the existing file is src/README.txt. That file will be looked up (relative to the location of the spec file) and copied into the top level of the bundled app.
>
> The strings may use either / or \ as the path separator character. You can specify input files using “glob” abbreviations. For example to include all the .mp3 files from a certain folder:

```
a = Analysis(...
     datas= [ ('/mygame/sfx/*.mp3', 'sfx' ) ],
     ...
     )
```

Comment: I believe this would work for me but pyinstaller seems to have issues with Windows 10 and late versions of Python